# Why hasn't Caja been popular?

Tags: javascript, security, google

Google released [Caja](http://code.google.com/p/google-caja/) around 2008(Capability JavaScript). It is still mainly a laboratory language. But XSS and other attacks would be prevented if there was widespread integration of Caja.

Comment: why downvotes? please say

Comment: I'm sure that the, "More wood behind fewer arrows" policy (http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2011/07/more-wood-behind-fewer-arrows.html) is not helping. Caja doesn't have anything to do with "social" (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jw_on_tech/archive/2012/03/13/why-i-left-google.aspx)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I am the technical lead for Caja.  Since it's initial release, we've been iterating on the design and implementation of Caja. With each iteration we've made the input we accept as input larger (and closer to plain-old-javascript), and our output faster and more debuggable.  During our testing we found that the lack of these features made adoption by developers difficult.

Our current iteration is based on ES5-strict support in modern browsers and executes at full speed and with a sufficiently simple translation as to be negligible during debugging.  We're not quite done with all the features of the new version but you can try it out experimentally at http://caja.appspot.com/?es5=true .  We expect our modern version of Caja to see a lot greater adoption.

We will continue to support older browsers with our existing server-side translation version and existing sites can start using it today and start getting the modern version based on the version of the browser soon.  For example, Google Sites uses Caja to sandbox HTML Box in this way.

For more information on how to embed content using Caja, see https://developers.google.com/caja